# what is the fwidth glsl function actually used for?

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering, glsl, shader

Every time I drunk browse so I see an unanswered `fwidth` question.
And it makes me wonder what it actually was designed to do.

Reading the docs it is:
`abs(dFdx(p)) + abs(dFdy(p))`

So it is not classic mip selection which is `max(dx,dy)`.
Is it for alternative mip selection? But I fail to find a case where `abs(dx) + abs(dy)` would be better.
There must be some siggraph paper or common algorithm I am completely missing that uses that function. And it must be really popular because it made it into GLSL.
The only thing I can think of is some 2d post filter I am missing.
But what?
I am sure somebody here knows and once you see it it's obvious.
So: What algorithm uses `abs(dx) + abs(dy)`?

Comment: The 2D post filtering you mention is a decent example actually.

Comment: Take your pick. Anti-aliasing, edge detection, anisotropic filtering. Actually, after some Google-ing I found an example use [here](http://prideout.net/blog/?p=22) where it's used for anti-aliasing of a cel shading shader.

Comment: chatting in comments now :) i found that stuff also but it does not seem important enough to make it into the language. there must be something else! for 2d the only thing i could think of is that it is maybe an ok prediction. i still feel like there is some blaring obvious thing for it though.

Comment: @starmole: Just because it doesn't "seem important" to you doesn't mean that it isn't important. Bart gave you 4 scenarios where the function would be of value. By all rights, that should have been an answer.

Comment: @starmole I don't know how much more magical you expect it to be, in order to count as important? It's an often used type of function in scenarios similar to those I mentioned. I don't know the nitty gritty details of what it boils down to in terms of the actual "code" sent to the GPU, but I could imagine some advantage of this single function over evaluating calls to dFdx and dFdy yourself. But that's pure speculation on my part.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're actually quite on the money with the 2D filtering suggestion. Any filter which relies on some sort of metric for the rate of change between a pixel and its neighbors could benefit from this function.

Examples would be anti-aliasing, edge detection, anisotropic filtering. I'm sure there are more examples one could think of.

It seems from your question and comments that you expect there to be a mind-blowing reason for this function to be included in GLSL. I would just say that it's a useful function to have. Perhaps someone with more in-depth knowledge about the actual internals of this function could provide more detail on what happens behind the scenes (i.e. if there is any performance improvement over a handwritten equivalent with dFdx and dFdy).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It does make sense. What I was looking for was really something "mindblowing". For example looking at the GLSL noise function, I know what why it is there, why it needs to be driven by input etc. But only because I knew about Perlin noise before! So I kind of assume this function is similarly important in some algorithm I just don't know about. But with the age of the question and nobody answering with a siggraph link you are probably right: It's a useful shortcut, easy to implement and emulate. Anyhow, thanks for the patience and sorry if I seemed a bit douchy :)

Comment: Here is a good-looking example of shader using fwidth as well: [terrain-contour-lines](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/529926-terrain-contour-lines-using-pixel-shader/)

Answer (score 4):

this is the total derivative for the function DF = dF/dx*dx + dF/dy*dy  .see the similarity? 
fWidth >= DF or in words fWidth is maximum possible change in a fragment variable F, between any of a current fragmants neighboring pixels.  ie the 8 surrounding pixels in the 3x3 neighborhood.